# Creating design document from existing java code

Tags: sdlc

I have existing java code and need to create Design Document based on that.

For starter even if I could get all functions with input / output parameters that will help in overall proces.

Note: There is not commeted documentation on any procedures, function or classes.

Last but not least. Let me know for any good tool which will reduce time required for this phase. As currently we write every flow and related stuffs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is just too much. Quoting Linus Torvalds: “Good code is its own best documentation.”. Anyway, I digress.

You might want to look into UML tools which generate class/sequence diagrams from the code. There are many of them but only a handful support reverse engineering (into and from the class diagram), and even fewer subset support the same to/from sequence diagram. I only know MagicDraw could do this, but I am biased as I used to work for the manufacturer of this tool so do your shopping around first.

Comment: not exactly what i was expecting but close one. I guess for me the approch would be more like DIY, Thanks mindas

Comment: Linus comment assumes good code.  People need a design doc if the code isn't good.  What the asker wants would be a godsend.

Answer (score 0):

Use java docs: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html

or Introspection: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classMembers.html